# Robots.txt and locations that are not referenced

Tags: web-crawler, robots.txt

If I want to protect a folder from being crawled by robots that respect standards I can disallow it from robots.txt.

Now, the problem I get is that by hiding a folder, I am showing its existence to others.

So, do I have to specify a folder I do not want crawled in robots.txt if there are no links to it? "Good" crawlers only follow links right, they don't search for folders and files randomly.

Thank you.

Comment: Security through obscurity rarely works. Especially on the internet. If "not giving out links" is your only defense for those locations, then you **should** consider that defense broken at all times.

Comment: Don't worry it's more than that, but I preffer having as many obstacles as possible even if simple ones if they won't cost me anything, not even time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the `Disallow` lines in `robots.txt` are prefixes, you could just mention a prefix to your "hidden" directory that it doesn't share with any "public" directories.

So if your "hidden" directory is called `/topsecrete_donotread/` then you could use `Disallow: /tops` to avoid it being crawled.

Comment: Hm, that's clever, I didn't know I could disallow folders that start with something.

Answer (score 3):

Let me assure you, as the author of a "good" web crawler, that if there's something publicly accessible on the Web, a crawler *will* find it. If you create a folder like `http://example.com/hidden_folder` and think that by not publishing links to it nobody will find it, you're wrong. It's no better than hiding your house key under the door mat. Although a crawler likely won't go searching for `hidden_folder`, others will. And when they find it, they'll post a link to it, and my crawler will find that link.

The same sort of thing can happen even if nobody goes looking for your hidden folder. For example, imagine that you have a file `http://example.com/hidden_folder/bookmarks.html`. In it, you have links to all your favorite sites.

When you click on one of those links (say, joesblog.com), the request your browser sends to joesblog.com includes the referring url--the html file in your "hidden" folder.

You'd be surprised at how many sites publish their access logs. If joesblog is one of them, then somewhere on that site you're going to see a file that says, in effect, "joesblog.com was accessed from http://example.com/hidden_folder/bookmarks.html."

As others have said, security through obscurity doesn't work. If there's some information on your site that you don't want accessed, then protect it with a password or some other method. Do not assume that crawlers or people won't find it just because you didn't explicitly tell them about it.

Edit:

If you don't list the folders in your robots.txt file, then robots will crawl them, given a link. If you do list the folders, then "good" bots will not crawl. "Bad" bots will crawl regardless.

In my opinion, the likelihood of somebody reading your robots.txt in order to find links to hidden directories is lower than the likelihood of those links being discovered by other means. I would suggest using the solution proposed by @Joachim, which will prevent "good" bots from crawling, and won't reveal the exact directory name.

Also, if you disable directory listing and don't have a default page in your folder, then a bot going to `http://example.com/hidden_folder/` won't get anything but an error message saying that the directory contents can't be listed.

Comment: My question got misinterpreted. I am asking if it is better not to specify folders that are hidden in robots.txt rather than specifying them, not if it's better to not have any other security options.